# how to download files using pyqt5 webenginewidgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, python-webbrowser

I am learning pyqt5 and built a simple webbrowser in pyqt5 webengine .
Now out of curiosity I want to know that is there a method by which I am able to download files using this minimalistic browser,Thanks in advance.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtGui,QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w=QWebEngineView()
w.page().fullScreenRequested.connect(QWebEngineFullScreenRequest.accept)
w.load(QtCore.QUrl('https://google.com'))
w.showMaximized()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest possible way to download would be something like this...

```
def _downloadRequested(item): # QWebEngineDownloadItem
    print('downloading to', item.path())
    item.accept()

w.page().profile().downloadRequested.connect(_downloadRequested)
```